# How do you connect vertex groups to an armature?

Tags: armature, vertex-groups, pose-mode

[image]
I downloaded the awesome Daft Punk model created by Karol Miklas from [Sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/daft-punk-rigged-cuioiaVozDvNWn2yzigo1T93GIO) and have been trying to pose the figures within but I'm not able to. I'm missing the link between the vertex groups provided in the Blender file and an armature in my project.

[image]

I've watched a lot of YouTube videos for rigging characters and tried Googling for the answer but nothing I've found seems to relate to what I'm trying to accomplish. Being a newbie, I know I'm missing something that's obvious to the more experienced; can you share what steps need to be taken to connect the vertex groups to an armature for posing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is give your bones the name of the vertex group they are supposed to control then parent your mesh to the armature with a simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Armature Deform*. Each bone will automatically control the group with the same name.

Comment: Hi moonboots, thanks for the suggestion. I made a short screen capture of what happens when I try that; grabbing the hand and moving it results in the arm moving in an unexpected way. The bones are named correctly so I'm not quite sure why this happens (also, attempting to grab and move other bones doesn't always move the mesh).
https://youtu.be/Fon7OT2nlok

Comment: I think there are too many parameters there, maybe you should start from scratch, but do you have a rest pose (T pose) for your meshes?

Comment: No, unfortunately, that's how the model came with the two figures already in that jumping/crouched pose. Is it fair to say it's game over with not having them in a T pose? If so, it confuses me that the author says that the model is rigged for animation as you're given the vertex groups but not the original armature.

Comment: if the author says it is rigged, then you should find an armature in the file, that could be brought back to its rest pose.

Comment: if not, there's a new sculpt brush in 2.8, a Pose brush that could help you to bring the mesh back to a T pose (seems much more convenient than doing it in Edit mode): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OrhfjhdlRUc

Comment: Hey that's a really handy suggestion (at time of this writing, face sets is a new feature in 2.83 alpha)! I'm going to have to play around with this because after creating the UV seams and trying to pose the various body parts I get mixed results (sometimes the parts get disconnected from each other and can't be posed). Failing that, I'm just going to have to go back to the drawing board and use a different character. Thanks moonboots!